# PDO bindParam isn't working

Tags: php, pdo

I am inserting data in database dynamically without assigning column in code. This works fine if I don't bind. But, when I tried to bind, it doesn't work

Working fine

```
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $text = $_POST["text"];  
    $column_name = $_POST["column_name"];  
    $result = $con->query("UPDATE menu SET $column_name=$text WHERE id=$id") OR die($con->error);  
    echo "Data updated";
```

But it doesn't work.

```
$result = $con->prepare("UPDATE menu SET :column_name=:text WHERE id=:id")or die($con->error);
            $result->bindparam(':id',$_POST['id']);
            $result->bindparam(':text',$_POST['text']);
            $result->bindparam(':column_name',$_POST['column_name']);
            if($result->execute()){
                echo "Data Updated";
            }
```

Comment: I don't think you can pass the column name like that. You will likely need ot sanitize it yourself and put it in the query string.

Comment: Long answer short, no you can't bind column names. Long answer, long? Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15990488/2518525

Comment: @S.Dev, is it secure  ? -: `$_POST['id'] = filter_var($_POST['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`